# ios, is there a way to show MKPinAnnotationView without user tap the pin on MapView?

Tags: ios

as topic,

I just want a way that can show the MKPinAnnotationView without click the pin on MapView ?

I try to use the method `- (void)selectAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation animated:(BOOL)animated;`

but it seem only can select one pin but many .... I want show all MKPinAnnotationView of the pins , anyone know how to do ?

thanks for u help .

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done it personally, but if I were you i will try to get `image` properties of these `MKPinAnnotationView` obejcts and show them in an arrangement of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can think in this way, you "tap" it, show the annotation, so what's tap?

```
- (void)selectAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Answer (score 0):

for loop?

- (void)selectAnnotation:(id )annotation animated:(BOOL)animated;